# Change default udp multicast ttl at linux

Tags: linux, multicast, ttl

Is there any method to change udp multicast ttl at linux system level ?
I already know use setsockopt to set IP_MULTICAST_TTL in application. But i want to change ttl in system level.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the UDP multicast TTL at system level for all packets (not just multicast packets) is not directly supported in Linux.There is no system-wide configuration option in Linux that allows setting the TTL for multicast packets independently of other IP packets. If you want to enforce a specific TTL value for multicast packets at system level, you would typically need to implement this logic within your application.

applications that need to control the multicast packets TTL specifically, you can use the [setsockopt()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) function with the IP_MULTICAST_TTL option in the application code. This allows for fine-grained control over the TTL for multicast packets at the application level, without affecting other types of IP traffic.

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this and vote to close